# Force Gnome Network Manager to use WPA2

Tags: networking, network-manager, wpa2

I flashed OpenWrt on my wireless router and set it to mixed WPA2/WPA3. All of my wireless devices worked fine except one: an older ThinkPad T430u running Ubuntu 22.04.

It worked before on the exact same router before I flashed it, so on a whim I set the router to WPA2 only, and now the T430u connects again.

Ideally I would like to set the router back to WPA2/WPA3 mixed mode, and tell Ubuntu to use WPA2.

If I open the connection in Network Manager, in the *Security* tab I see *WPA & WPA2 Personal* as an option. However, on another machine I selected *WPA & WPA2 Personal* and if I go to *Details* under *Security* it says *WPA3* (before I changed the router to WPA2 only).

How can I force Ubuntu to use WPA2?

Here are the logs from when it was failing:

```
Oct 21 13:06:22 hostname NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1666371982.0904] policy: auto-activating connection 'MY_WIFI' (b0a3a436-f4c1-49f0-9acf-9fb49fb07e8f)
Oct 21 13:06:22 hostname NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1666371982.0921] device (wlp3s0): Activation: starting connection 'MY_WIFI' (b0a3a436-f4c1-49f0-9acf-9fb49fb07e8f)
Oct 21 13:06:22 hostname NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1666371982.0924] device (wlp3s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 21 13:06:22 hostname NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1666371982.0941] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Oct 21 13:06:22 hostname NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1666371982.0949] device (wlp3s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 21 13:06:22 hostname NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1666371982.0957] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'MY_WIFI' has security, but secrets are required.
Oct 21 13:06:22 hostname NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1666371982.0958] device (wlp3s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 21 13:06:22 hostname NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1666371982.1009] device (wlp3s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 21 13:06:22 hostname NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1666371982.1025] device (wlp3s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 21 13:06:22 hostname NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1666371982.1037] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'MY_WIFI' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Oct 21 13:06:22 hostname NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1666371982.1039] Config: added 'ssid' value 'MY_WIFI'
Oct 21 13:06:22 hostname NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1666371982.1039] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Oct 21 13:06:22 hostname NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1666371982.1039] Config: added 'bssid' value '07:78:3B:81:D2:1A'
Oct 21 13:06:22 hostname NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1666371982.1040] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256'
Oct 21 13:06:22 hostname NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1666371982.1040] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
Oct 21 13:06:22 hostname NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1666371982.2553] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Oct 21 13:06:26 hostname NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1666371986.3667] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> disconnected
Oct 21 13:06:26 hostname NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1666371986.8684] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Oct 21 13:06:30 hostname NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1666371990.8684] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> disconnected
Oct 21 13:06:31 hostname NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1666371991.8745] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Oct 21 13:06:35 hostname NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1666371995.9916] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> disconnected
Oct 21 13:06:40 hostname NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1666372000.9993] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Oct 21 13:06:46 hostname NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1666372006.0066] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> disconnected
Oct 21 13:06:47 hostname NetworkManager[864]: <warn>  [1666372007.4528] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) association took too long, failing activation
Oct 21 13:06:47 hostname NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1666372007.4529] device (wlp3s0): state change: config -> failed (reason 'ssid-not-found', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 21 13:06:47 hostname NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1666372007.4542] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Oct 21 13:06:47 hostname NetworkManager[864]: <warn>  [1666372007.4553] device (wlp3s0): Activation: failed for connection 'MY_WIFI'
Oct 21 13:06:47 hostname NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1666372007.4561] device (wlp3s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
```

And here are the logs after I changed the router to use WPA2 only:

```
Oct 21 13:11:33 hostname NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1666372293.9722] policy: auto-activating connection 'MY_WIFI' (b0a3a436-f4c1-49f0-9acf-9fb49fb07e8f)
Oct 21 13:11:33 hostname NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1666372293.9820] device (wlp3s0): Activation: starting connection 'MY_WIFI' (b0a3a436-f4c1-49f0-9acf-9fb49fb07e8f)
Oct 21 13:11:33 hostname NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1666372293.9823] device (wlp3s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 21 13:11:33 hostname NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1666372293.9835] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Oct 21 13:11:33 hostname NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1666372293.9850] device (wlp3s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 21 13:11:33 hostname NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1666372293.9858] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'MY_WIFI' has security, but secrets are required.
Oct 21 13:11:33 hostname NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1666372293.9859] device (wlp3s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 21 13:11:33 hostname NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1666372293.9958] device (wlp3s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 21 13:11:33 hostname NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1666372293.9965] device (wlp3s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 21 13:11:33 hostname NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1666372293.9972] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'MY_WIFI' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Oct 21 13:11:33 hostname NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1666372293.9973] Config: added 'ssid' value 'MY_WIFI'
Oct 21 13:11:33 hostname NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1666372293.9973] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Oct 21 13:11:33 hostname NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1666372293.9973] Config: added 'bssid' value '07:78:3B:81:D2:1A'
Oct 21 13:11:33 hostname NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1666372293.9974] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256'
Oct 21 13:11:33 hostname NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1666372293.9974] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
Oct 21 13:11:36 hostname NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1666372296.0439] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Oct 21 13:11:40 hostname NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1666372300.1260] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> associating
Oct 21 13:11:40 hostname NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1666372300.2926] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> 4way_handshake
Oct 21 13:11:40 hostname NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1666372300.3023] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: 4way_handshake -> completed
Oct 21 13:11:40 hostname NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1666372300.3024] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful. Connected to wireless network "MY_WIFI"
Oct 21 13:11:40 hostname NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1666372300.3026] device (wlp3s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 21 13:11:40 hostname NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1666372300.3038] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Oct 21 13:11:42 hostname NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1666372302.1066] dhcp6 (wlp3s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Oct 21 13:11:42 hostname NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1666372302.1120] dhcp6 (wlp3s0): state changed new lease, address=eefa:be00:31bd:6796:8f67:f3c8:1b05:170d
Oct 21 13:11:43 hostname NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1666372303.4636] device (wlp3s0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 21 13:11:43 hostname NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1666372303.4707] device (wlp3s0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 21 13:11:43 hostname NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1666372303.4711] device (wlp3s0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 21 13:11:43 hostname NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1666372303.4716] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Oct 21 13:11:43 hostname NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1666372303.4727] device (wlp3s0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Oct 21 13:11:43 hostname NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1666372303.8405] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): state changed new lease, address=192.168.0.166
Oct 21 13:11:43 hostname NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1666372303.8417] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Oct 21 13:11:43 hostname NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1666372303.8420] policy: set 'MY_WIFI' (wlp3s0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Oct 21 13:11:46 hostname NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1666372306.1178] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
```

Edit: I did some more digging, and there doesn't appear to be a way to force WPA2. The *WPA & WPA2 Personal* security setting is apparently misnamed and is actually for WPA2 + WPA3 personal:

```
$ nmcli conn edit wifi
nmcli> describe wifi-sec.key-mgmt

=== [key-mgmt] ===
[NM property description]
Key management used for the connection. One of "none" (WEP or no password protection), "ieee8021x" (Dynamic WEP), "owe" (Opportunistic Wireless Encryption), "wpa-psk" (WPA2 + WPA3 personal), "sae" (WPA3 personal only), "wpa-eap" (WPA2 + WPA3 enterprise) or "wpa-eap-suite-b-192" (WPA3 enterprise only). This property must be set for any Wi-Fi connection that uses security.
```

After that, I found a couple bugs which seem to describe what I'm seeing:

- [Mixed WPA2 and WPA3 support causes problems](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/-/issues/964)
- https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1003907

I noticed I was running wpasupplicant 2.10-6 and upgraded to 2.10-9, but it didn't fix the issue.

I also upgraded networkmanager to 1.40 and that didn't fix the issue.

I was able to further narrow down the problem to 802.11w; by default, the WPA2/WPA3 mixed mode setting in OpenWrt sets it to *Optional*, with a warning that some devices don't fully support 802.11w.

According to this: [Checking 802.11w (MFP/PMF) Support (on Linux)](https://kevinlocke.name/bits/2019/12/28/checking-802.11w-support/), my device (which uses a BCM43228 chipset) seems to report that it supports 802.11w:

```
$ iw phy phy0 info | grep 00-0f-ac:6
        * CMAC (00-0f-ac:6)
```

So either it's incorrectly reporting 802.11w support or there's another problem.

The only workarounds I've found are either to set the router to WPA2 only, or WPA2/WPA3 mixed mode with 802.11w disabled.